# SDL loading image when in struct

Tags: c, struct, sdl

So i'm having a problem I have a struct called Image and a funcion LoadImage and it works all fine but when I have something like this:

Animation.h

```
typedef struct Anim
{
Anim_data anim_data[20];
Image* img_anim; 
int curr;
}Anim;


void AnimLoad(char* name, Anim* a)
{
 ImageLoad("../../Resource/pingvin.jpeg", a->img_anim);

}
```

The ImageLoad function breaks i think it has something to do with a->img_anim but don't see what's wrong with it, works fine when i give a Image struct I don't have in a another struct.

So just to be clear the function works, it just doesn't when i give it a struct Image which I call from another struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You n eed to allocate space for a->img_anim like this:

```
 Anim a;
 a.img_anim = malloc(sizeof(Image *));
 a.img_anim = Address of image.
```

then in your function it should work.

Edit:

In the C99 specification of a structure, it is not initialized unless you initialize it manually such as:

```
 struct a{
 int member1;
 int member2;
 }

 struct a example = {.member1 = 2002,.member2 = 3003};  //This is initialization manually.  This is like manually allocating an array with
 //Int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
```

Otherwise you need to do this:

```
  struct a;
  a.member1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  a.member2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This gives member1 and member2 memory of size 4 bytes (which is an integer).
If you don't do this, member1 and member2 don't have spots in memory!

Comment: It works, thank you very much this is bugging me for hours, could you explain why I must dynamically allocate the memory here?

Comment: Why would need to allocate a normal int inside a struct? I have never seen this. When you create an instance of a struct the memory for the stuct is reserved but not initialized. Only pointers need to be malloced'ed seperately.

Comment: You're right, only pointers need to be initialized with malloc inside a struct.  I meant to make them int pointers.